# Scheduler Job not called in SpringBoot app

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, scheduled-tasks

I have this SpringBoot app:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
@Import({SecurityConfig.class})
public class BlogsApplication implements CommandLineRunner {
..
}
```

and I also have this class,

```
@Component 
public class UptadeCurrencyJob1 {

    @Scheduled(cron = "0 0/10 1 * * ?")
    public void reportCurrentTime() throws IOException {

            System.out.println("UptadeCurrencyJob1");       
    }
}
```

But it never calles

Comment: For the sake of argument, what do you think your cron expression is saying? Maybe you aren't waiting long enough?

Comment: Guess you missed to mention where your components are, try using @ComponentScan and give root path as the argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0/10 1 * * ?")
```

Indeed, this is valid cron expresion meaning that it will fire every 10 minutes past midnight (for 1 hour only). I bet you did not wait that long nor you did mean that.